# Eloquent sum of units within duration from date

Tags: eloquent

I have a table (projects) which contains a start_date and duration (in weeks) and a number (progress_pw) as to how much progress units can be achieved per week

```
projects
+----+----------+--------+-----------+
| ID |start_date|duration|progress_pw|
+----+----------+--------+-----------+
|  1 |2018-06-15| 2      | 500       |
|  2 |2018-06-19| 4      | 120       |
```

I want to get a summary by week of the total number of progress units expected to be used in that given week.

Eg:

*In the week starting Monday 11 June project.id 1 is expected to consume 500 units

*In the week starting Monday 18 June project.id 1 is expected to consume 500 units & project.id 2 is expected to consume 120 units with a total consumption of 620 units.

*In the week starting 2018-12-01 (sometime in the future) there are no active projects so 0 units consumed.

```php
$i=0;$weeks=12;
while ($i < $weeks) {
    $thisweek = Carbon::now()->addWeeks($i)->startOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d');
    $requiredcap = DB::table('projects')->select(DB::raw("sum(progress_pw) as progress"))

    ->where('install_date', ">=", $thisweek) //<<< This is where im getting stuck!

    ->get();

    $capacity['label'][] = Carbon::now()->addWeeks($i)->startOfWeek()->format('d M');
    $capacity['required'][] = $requiredcap;
    $i++;
}
```

Any pointers of the logic behind this one?

Comment: Can you add an `end_date` column to the table? That would make it a lot easier.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Yes, I have a feeling I will need to do this just to make this query simpler. Will auto calculate the end date based on start and duration to add to db.

Comment: Will the `end_date` be exactly `$duration` weeks after the `start_date`? Or always a Sunday?

Comment: yes 'end_date' will be exactly '$duration' weeks after the 'start_date'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
$i = 0; $weeks = 12;
while ($i < $weeks) {
    $start = Carbon::now()->addWeeks($i)->startOfWeek();
    $end = (clone $start)->addDays(6);
    $requiredcap = DB::table('projects')
        ->select(DB::raw('sum(progress_pw) as progress'))
        ->whereBetween('start_date', [$start->toDateString(), $end->toDateString()])
        ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($start, $end) {
            $query->where('start_date', '<', $start->toDateString())
                ->where('end_date', '>=', $start->toDateString());
        })->first();
    $capacity['label'][] = $start->format('d M');
    $capacity['required'][] = $requiredcap->progress;
    $i++;
}
```